# For loop information on Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

How to add For loop information to Multi-Dimensional Array?
http://jsfiddle.net/MZj3L/
If I am trying this code get - map undefined. But how to save data something like to this ->

```
[[Array[10], [Array[10], [Array[10], [Array[10], [Array[10], [Array[10], [Array[10], [Array[10], [Array[10], [Array[10]]
```

Thanks and sorry for my English language.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is it exactly that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: In your example you say `map = [a][b];` It would help if you referenced the actual array, for example `map = myArray[a][b];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in you want to initialize a multi dimensional array. Arrays are dynamic in JavaScript, you don't have to initialize them with a certain length. You could just do:

```
var map = [];

for(var a = 0; a < 10; a++){
    map[a] = [];
}
```

This gives you an array containing 10 arrays.

---

Why are you getting `undefined`?

Because your syntax is way of. What `map = [a][b];` does is creating an array with one element `a` and then accessing the `b`th element of that array and assign it to `map`.

So in the last iteration, it does:

```
map = [9][9];
```

which is the same as

```
tmp = [9];
map = tmp[9];
```

Comment: Thanks, too Thanks all other's who write to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
var map = [];

for(var a = 0; a < 10; a++){
    map[a]=[];
    for(var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
        map[a].push(b);
    }
}
```

I am not sure what you want to do either but that's the only think I could do with your code ...